# How many critical values does $f$ have on $(0,10)$, given $f '(x)=\frac{\cos^2 x}{x} -\frac{1}{5}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How many critical values does $f$ have on open interval $(0, 10)$ given $$f'(x) = \frac{\cos^2x}{x} - \frac{1}{5}$$

I'm in calculus AB and this is a review question. I think the next step is to make it
$$\cos x = \sqrt{\frac{x}{5}}$$

But I am not really sure.

Comment: Correction: $\cos x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{x}{5}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $5\cos^2 x = x$.  $f(x)$ will have critical values when $f'(x) = 0$.  Draw the graphs of $y = x$ and $y = 5\cos^2 x$ and see how many times the graphs intersect on $(0,10)$.  You should get 3 intersections which means 3 critical points.

Comment: this makes sense because this was a calculator question and i totally forgot i could graph it FailFish

Comment: You don't need a calculator to figure out how many times they intersect.  You just need to know when $\cos x = \pm 1,0$.